# Optimize code for rounding off of a BigDecimal number

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a scenario where i'm getting an amount in the form of String and I need to round it off and send as a String what I did is :

```
public static String roundOff(String pfEmpWithoutRoundOff) {
        try {

            BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(pfEmpWithoutRoundOff);
            int value = bigDecimal.intValue();
            int length = String.valueOf(value).length();
            BigDecimal rounded = bigDecimal.round(new MathContext(length, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            return String.valueOf(rounded);
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Well is there a way I can **optimize the code**. I have some 5 lines which does it can I do it some 2-3 lines.

Comment: it may belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was thinking if someone can help me out here

Comment: Maybe String format? Is amount really large to make it BigDecimal?
String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", rawprice);

Comment: @IvanIvanov want it in BigDecimal just want to be in the safe side in case of some large amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
return new BigDecimal(pfEmpWithoutRoundOff).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();
```

?

Comment: How to use setScale() if the have different scale for different input string?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Can you just provide me a few examples what output do you expect for what input?

Comment: ok ok i misinterpreted that MathContext()'s int setPrecision with setScale(). it its doing the job grt :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (*if you like*), it has only **2 lines** for rounding-off the `String` :

```
public static String roundOff(String pfEmpWithoutRoundOff) {
    Long roundVal = Math.round(Double.valueOf(pfEmpWithoutRoundOff));
    return roundVal.toString();
}
```

Comment: I dont want to take risk with long or double i want BigDecimal

Comment: then use `new BigDecimal(pfEmpWithoutRoundOff).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` as suggested by Michael.